# Dark Themed status bar

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, gdm

Status bar has got a dark theme(Screenshot attatched).I installed kubuntu desktop. Then I removed it along with all other files. Also, i restarted lightdm. Did'nt work out. Then I removed lightdm and installed gdm. Problem still persists.All the options in the image sholud have been highlighted. What do I do?[image]